# Two columns accordion with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and in the design, we have a two col accordion section that can only have one active drop down state at time.

I'm running into an issue with maintaining the cols after clicking dropdown. The elements on the left keep shifting right under the expanded section.

Please, see the example: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/JCL2XR59WE)

CODE:

```
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-7">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">


    <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne1">
            TEST1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo2">
TEST 2       </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTEST        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree3">
TEST3        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTEST       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour4">
TEST   4     </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTEST       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>






  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive5">
TEST  5      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTEST        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix6">
TEST    6    </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSix6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTEST       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">
TEST  7      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEight">
TEST  8      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseEight" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNine">
TEST  9      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseNine" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTen">
TEST     10   </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>






  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEleven">
TEST  11      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseEleven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwelve">
TEST    12    </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwelve" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
</div>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you also add relevant code into your question as well

Comment: oh hey, see the example pen under the question.

Comment: I know you have the pen which is actually more helpful but the SO guidelines state your question must include 'the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself' good to get in the practice now, http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: gotcha. added it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than adding the `col-sm-6` around each panel, group the two sides in their own divs and add the 'col-sm-6' to each group

example: http://www.bootply.com/vfbv3Cnn6v

```
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-7">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

        <!-- start panel left -->
        <div class="panel-left col-sm-6">
            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_1">
                        TEST_1
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_2">
                        TEST_2
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_3">
                        TEST_3
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_4">
                        TEST_4
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_5">
                        TEST_5
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_6">
                        TEST_6
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->




        </div> 
        <!-- end panel left -->


        <!-- start panel right -->
        <div class="panel-left col-sm-6">
            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_7">
                        TEST_7
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_8">
                        TEST_8
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_9">
                        TEST_9
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_10">
                        TEST_10
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_10" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_11">
                        TEST_11
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_11" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->

            <!-- start panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TEST_12">
                        TEST_12
                     </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="TEST_12" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->




        </div> 
        <!-- end panel right -->




    </div>
</div>
```

Also i find when i have large groups of nested divs it is handy to add comments to show where the opening and closing of important areas are.

so to get the accordion to still respect the opening and closing the bootstrap docs says there is an event `show.bs.collapse` which is fired when showing a panel so use that to then hide which ever panel has the class `in` (this denotes the open panel)

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: but the accordions won't toggle one at a time unless nested

Comment: Ha, yep completely missed that was looking to see if they swapped, i'll edit my answer

Comment: updated answer, was trying to find a method that didn't involve js but I couldn't think of a way to stop the two col's messing with each other if they were not grouped in their own div. and to go with that method a little js has to be used to get the accordion working again

Comment: It's not bootstrap, but here's a working version I just got some help with that uses two floated columns, and can auto-collapse across columns (keeps only one expanded at a time).   https://codepen.io/bibbli/pen/XWdvJzG